# Query Tokens in SXA

Tags: sxa

In SXA's out of the box renderings, I see datasource locations that look like this:

```
query:$site/*[@@name='Data']/*[@@templatename='Custom Folder']
```

Is `$site` the only token supported here?  Can I inject my own tokens?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### SXA tokens

There are other tokens as well:

- `$compatibleThemes` - path to all themese
- `$theme` - currently used theme
- `$pageDesigns` - root of page designs
- `$partialDesigns` - root of partial designs
- `$currenttemplate` - name of the current template
- `$tenant` - path to the current tenant
- `$site` - path to the current site
- `$home` - path to the current site start item (Home)
- `$linkableHomes` - paths home items from linkable sites (see [cross-site linking](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/adjust-link-settings-to-enable-cross-site-linking.html))
- `$templates` - path to the current sitetemplates
- `$siteMedia` - path to Virtual Media folder located under site
- `$sharedSites` - for multiroot fields, resovles shared site for current tenant.
- `$rvSystemTemplates` - returns list of templates defined in a configuration. Those template are used to feed `AllowedInTemplates` field for rendering variants.
- `$xaRichTextProfile` - returns `XA.Foundation.Editing.DefaultRichTextProfile` setting value.

#### Introduced with 10.2

- `$sitelang` - the context site language.
- `$lang` - the context language.
- `$vf` - the virtual folder for the context site.

#### How to define custom tokens

You can define your own tokens by adding an additional processor to `resolveTokens` pipeline

Answer (score 2):

Updated with 9.3 Resolve and Query Tokens

**Resolve Tokens**

- `$compatibleThemes` - path to all themes.
- `$theme` - currently used theme.
- `$pageDesigns` - root of page designs
  (sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Presentation/Page Designs).
- `$partialDesigns` - root of partial designs
  (/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Presentation/Partial Designs) .
- `$currenttemplate` - name of the current template.
- `$tenant` - path to the current tenant.
- `$site` - path to the current site.
- `$home` - path to the current site start item (by default:
  /sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Home).
- `$linkableHomes` - paths to home items from linkable sites.
- `$templates` - path to the current site templates
  (/sitecore/templates/Project/Tenant).
- `$siteMedia` - paths to media folders specified in Additional Children 
  field on virtual media folder item.
- `$sharedSites` - for multiroot fields, resolves shared site for the
  current tenant.
- `$rvSystemTemplates` - list of templates defined in a configuration.
  These templates are used to feed the AllowedInTemplates field for
  rendering variants.
- `$xaRichTextProfile` - the XA.Foundation.Editing.DefaultRichTextProfile
  setting value.

**Query Tokens**

The resolveSearchQueryTokens pipeline is used to add search filters. This pipeline is defined in the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.config file. By default, the following tokens are available:

- `TaggedTheSameAsCurrentPage|SxaTags`
- `TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags`
- `UnderCurrentPage`
- `ExcludeCurrentPage`
- `ItemsOfTheSameTemplateAsTheCurrentPage`
- `ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|FieldName`

[9.3 documentation link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-pipelines.html)

Answer (score -1):

please follow below links for details in token customization.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-custom-token-for-a-rendering-variant.html

You have to extend the "resolveVariantTokens" processor.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. There's a difference between the varianttokens and tokens.

He has to extend the "resolveTokens" processor instead of "resolveVariantTokens". There are also plenty of great guides for that though, e.g. http://blog.binboy.net/post/sxa-create-custom-token-query