Sitecore Scriban is not rendering fields when using dynamic field values
I have this Scriban template:
{{
  mediaId = sc_field i_item 'DropLinkField'

  item_By_Id = (sc_getitem mediaId)

  item_harcoded = "{ADAF43DF-BFD6-4444-9FE9-A030AB70B873}"

  get_the_url = (sc_getitem item_harcoded)

}}

<p>MediaId = {{mediaId}}</p>

<p>item_By_Id = {{item_By_Id}}</p>

<p>get_the_url = {{get_the_url}}</p>

<img src = "{{item_By_Id.media_url}}"/>

<img src="{{get_the_url.media_url}}"/>

Output

mediaId: {ADAF43DF-BFD6-4444-9FE9-A030AB70B873}
item_By_Id:
get_the_url: /sitecore/media library/Project/Experiment/KV/First/linkedin_icon
Image is displayed for the get_the_url one

If I put the 2nd last image tag (the one with the item_By_Id) then I get this error:
Scriban(11,26) : error : Cannot get the member item_By_Id.media_url for a null object.
Sitecore Scriban doesn't seem to support dynamic values. As from the output I can see that item_By_Id is empty.

What is the main purpose of the above code? Are you trying to get the media URL from an image field?

The droplink field populates the mediaItems. Once the content author choses the option, I want to render the image. So what I am doing is getting the item id of the chosen value. And then trying to get the media item as the src of img field.

Which version of SXA are you using? Did you try any of the options in here? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/get-item-by-path-or-id-using-scriban-in-sitecore

In that case, you could use sc_follow command: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/latest/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html#sc_medialink

@MarcelGruber I am using SXA 10.0. I have tried the options there. The problem I am facing is when I execute item_By_Id = (sc_getitem mediaId), it returns null which it shouldn't right?

Whenerver we use sc_field inside Scriban, it uses FieldRenderer pipeline in the background to get field value, therefore when you are in experience editor it will return the editable html as well.
sc_field function:

Editable HTML:

You can use below snippet directly to read the media url from the droplink using the help of sc_follow function.
{{ 
mediaItem = sc_follow i_item 'DropLinkField'
}}
{{ if mediaItem }} 
   <img src = "{{mediaItem.media_url}}"/>
{{ end }}

Using above way, you will be able to read droplink item id inside the CD server as well as experience editor.
Hope this helps!!!

Can you check updating 1st line as
mediaId = sc_raw i_item 'DropLinkField'

Hope this helps!!!

The issue seems to be that item_By_Id is coming out as null, which indicates that the sc_getitem function is not able to retrieve an item with the ID mediaId. Here are a few steps to check the issue:

Ensure the mediaId is correct: Verify that sc_field i_item 'DropLinkField' correctly retrieves the ID you expect. You can output mediaId to check its value.

Check if the item exists: Ensure that an item with the ID mediaId exists in the Sitecore database.


If mediaId is not null and correctly formatted, but sc_getitem still returns null, there might be an issue with how sc_getitem retrieves the item.
Alternatively, you can try below mentioned code and check:
{{
   mediaId = sc_field i_item 'DropLinkField'
}}
<p>MediaId = {{mediaId}}</p>
{{
   item_By_Id = null
   # Check if mediaId is not empty or null
   if mediaId != empty_string && mediaId != null {
       item_By_Id = sc_getitem mediaId
   }
}}
<p>item_By_Id = {{item_By_Id}}</p>
{{
   item_harcoded = "{ADAF43DF-BFD6-4444-9FE9-A030AB70B873}"
   get_the_url = sc_getitem item_harcoded
}}
<p>get_the_url = {{get_the_url}}</p>
<img src="{{item_By_Id.media_url}}" alt="Image from item_By_Id" />
<img src="{{get_the_url.media_url}}" alt="Image from get_the_url" />


mediaId is set from the DropLinkField.
Before using sc_getitem, we check if mediaId is not empty or null to avoid the null object error.
Only if mediaId is valid, we use sc_getitem to retrieve the item.
This part remains unchanged as it was working correctly.
Ensure that image tags use the media_url property.

